# Finding all combinations of two sets with k elements being exchanged

Tags: python, combinations

Lets say I have two list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']`. I want to create a set of two other list where k elements are being exchanged between the two lists:

Example for a single element:

```
['x', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'x', 'c', 'd'] ['b', 'y', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'] ['c', 'y', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'] ['d', 'y', 'z', 'w']
['y', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'a', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'y', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'b', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'] ['x', 'c', 'z', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'y'] ['x', 'd', 'z', 'w']
['z', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'a', 'w']
['a', 'z', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'b', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'z', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'c', 'w']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'z'] ['x', 'y', 'd', 'w']
['w', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']
['a', 'w', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'w', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'w'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'd']
```

Is there an efficient way to generate this kind of lists?

The only thing I can think of is swapping elements in a for loop:

```
list_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

for j in range(len(list_0)):
    for i in range(len(list_1)):
        list_0[i], list_1[j] = list_1[j], list_0[i]
        print(list_0, list_1)
        list_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        list_1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
```

This approach is very inefficient and am not sure how I could extend it to swapping k-elements.

Comment: is the order "inside" each pair important?

Comment: It is not, I'm only considering the combinations, not the permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the nested loops is as efficient as it gets, because you're basically generating a list of `[source_index, target_index]` pairs. Though re-creating the lists on every iteration is indeed wasteful.

Here's a more straightforward solution for k=1, using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

list_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

indexes = range(len(list_0))

for j, i in itertools.product(indexes, repeat=2):
    # Swap items.
    list_0[i], list_1[j] = list_1[j], list_0[i]
    print(list_0, list_1)
    # Swap back.
    list_0[i], list_1[j] = list_1[j], list_0[i]

    # Alternative without swapping, by creating new lists.
    # new_list_0 = [value if index != i else list_1[j] for index, value in enumerate(list_0)]
    # new_list_1 = [value if index != j else list_0[i] for index, value in enumerate(list_1)]
    # print(new_list_0, new_list_1)

# ['x', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'x', 'c', 'd'] ['b', 'y', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'] ['c', 'y', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'] ['d', 'y', 'z', 'w']
# ['y', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'a', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'y', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'b', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'] ['x', 'c', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'y'] ['x', 'd', 'z', 'w']
# ['z', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'a', 'w']
# ['a', 'z', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'b', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'z', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'c', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'z'] ['x', 'y', 'd', 'w']
# ['w', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']
# ['a', 'w', 'c', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'b']
# ['a', 'b', 'w', 'd'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'c']
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'w'] ['x', 'y', 'z', 'd']
```

And here's a general solution for any `k`:

```
import itertools

list_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
k = 2 # Number of elements to swap.

indexes = range(len(list_0))

for source_indexes in itertools.permutations(indexes, k):
    for target_indexes in itertools.combinations(indexes, k):
        # Swap elements.
        for target_index, source_index in zip(source_indexes, target_indexes):
            list_0[source_index], list_1[target_index] = list_1[target_index], list_0[source_index]

        print(list_0, list_1)

        # Swap back.
        for target_index, source_index in zip(source_indexes, target_indexes):
            list_0[source_index], list_1[target_index] = list_1[target_index], list_0[source_index]

# ['x', 'y', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'z', 'w']
# ['x', 'b', 'y', 'd'] ['a', 'c', 'z', 'w']
# ['x', 'b', 'c', 'y'] ['a', 'd', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'x', 'y', 'd'] ['b', 'c', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'x', 'c', 'y'] ['b', 'd', 'z', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'y'] ['c', 'd', 'z', 'w']
# ['x', 'z', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'b', 'w']
# ['x', 'b', 'z', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'c', 'w']
# ['x', 'b', 'c', 'z'] ['a', 'y', 'd', 'w']
# ['a', 'x', 'z', 'd'] ['b', 'y', 'c', 'w']
# ['a', 'x', 'c', 'z'] ['b', 'y', 'd', 'w']
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'z'] ['c', 'y', 'd', 'w']
# ['x', 'w', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'z', 'b']
# ['x', 'b', 'w', 'd'] ['a', 'y', 'z', 'c']
# ['x', 'b', 'c', 'w'] ['a', 'y', 'z', 'd']
# ['a', 'x', 'w', 'd'] ['b', 'y', 'z', 'c']
# ['a', 'x', 'c', 'w'] ['b', 'y', 'z', 'd']
# ['a', 'b', 'x', 'w'] ['c', 'y', 'z', 'd']
# ['y', 'x', 'c', 'd'] ['b', 'a', 'z', 'w']
# ...
```

Comment: Notice we have some "duplicates" if order doesn't matter: `['x', 'y', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'z', 'w']` on the first line and `['y', 'x', 'c', 'd'] ['b', 'a', 'z', 'w']` on the last line

Comment: The OP should clarify but I think the first `permutations` should be `combinations` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `combinations` and a `set`-theoretic approach to "merge" elements from one list to the other.

```
from itertools import combinations


l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l2 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

k = 2

s1 = set(l1)
s2 = set(l2)

cs1 = combinations(l1, r=k)
cs2 = list(combinations(l2, r=k))

L1, L2 = [], []
for c1 in cs1:
    s1_tmp_union = s1.symmetric_difference(c1).union

    for c2 in cs2:
        L1.append(s1_tmp_union(c2))
        L2.append(s2.symmetric_difference(c2).union(c1))

# check output
print(*zip(L1, L2), sep='\n')
```

The outputs are lists of sets. If a preferred datatype is needed it is possible to change it by performing the desired cast in the `append`-steps.

For example, if an belongingness order is required use `sorted`

```
.append(sorted(my_set, key=lambda x: x in s2)) # also returns a list
```

---

With `combinations` is grant that each pair of sublists is order invariant, so there is no further pair that, if sorted, is equal to it. To clarify,

| k | order invariant (*cards*) | all (*BoppreH*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 16 |
| 2 | 36 | 72 |
| 3 | 16 | 96 |
| 4 | 1 | 24 |

The case `k=4` where `4` is the length of the list it corresponds to an exchange of the two lists, so only one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools may help decrease runtime.
With the `itertools.product` method ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)), we can produce a list of tuples containing the pairs of indices that must be swapped.

```py
a, b = range(len(list_0)), range(len(list_1))
x = itertools.product(a, b)
for i, j in x:
  list_0[i], list_1[j] = list_1[j], list_0[i]
  print(list_0, list_1)
  list_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  list_1 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
```

Instead of running a nested loop, the code runs in a more linear fashion, although still maintaining the previous `O(n^2)` complexity of the previous function.
Through my own experimentation and timing with the `timethis` module, this method was faster just about 70% of the time, although further testing should be completed if this needs to be verified.

Comment: could you say more about the parameter of your workbench? `number`, `parameter`, 1st execution of the workbench?